# Regressing on many outcomes in a spatial model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spatial, ecology

I'm measuring many microbe populations in a 'river model' ecosystem by sampling at two points. I want to test the hypothesis that key species upstream are the best predictors for any given population at a sample site downstream (and I want to describe the best predictors).

A few questions.

The first is a general question about regression with many outcomes: the population level of any of hundreds of species could be important. So do I need to be concerned with using linear regression on all the upstream species to predict each downstream, species response vector? I'm thinking the problem here is false discovery due to multiple comparisons.

2) With many features and potential predictors, what is the best regression method to use? I expect that closely related species will be the best predictors of downstream populations... so CARTs to intuitively combine features? PCA/feature selection to reduce dimensions to related components? Or just let a linear model (glm?) algo 'factor out' unimportant features?

3) The spatial component is pretty simple. I expect downstream species abundance to be predictable from species upstream. So the interesting thing here would probably be species abundance that we can't explain. That being said, is it necessary to deal with potential correlation between the two sites? My preference is to ignore this component for now.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Because you're dealing with a stream, I think time series analysis may actually be more appropriate than spatial methods. In spatial analysis, we typically think of each observation being correlated with all the points around it. But in your case, it seems that downstream events would be correlated with upstream events, but not vice-versa.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. It's not actually a stream ecosystem. It's a 'people' ecosystem. We have upstream and downstream samples from the GI tract. So the variance is generated from sampling different individuals, but I only have 1 time point per individual. Really, what I want to know is if I can just ignore potential spatial correlation between the two sites when performing a regression.

Comment: I still cannot understand what you're measuring. What do you mean by 'population level'? Are measuring which aspect of microbial population? Also, the description of the problem with upstream and downstream needs to be clearified